# How can I get the value of a property at a specific key frame?

Tags: python, keyframes, lighting

I have a pretty basic scene where a light's power goes from 3000 to 0, keyframed at frame 0 and 80. How can I use python to retrieve the value of the 'Power' property at any specific frame?

I know I can access the object's power by using

```
power = obj.data.energy
```

but I don't know how I can make that dependent on a specific frame.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to change to the desired frame and access the property normally.

```
frame = 24
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
power = obj.data.energy  # value on frame 24
```